# Adding TFS add-in into Teams

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-teams

We have TFS 2015 (on-premise) and Microsoft Teams in the cloud.

I am trying to find the TFS plug-in (all I can see is Azure DevOps) and want to be able to show TFS information inside of Teams.

I see lots of articles on how this use to work?  But can't find it in my list of plugins to add into the system.

Is there something we need to do at a server level?

Thanks

Comment: TFS 2015 didn't support installing extensions directly from the marketplace. However, you should be able to install extensions manually by downloading the VSIX and uploading them to TFS. That's no guarantee that modern extensions will be compatible with a 4+ year old version of TFS, but you can try. Refer to the TFS 2015 documentation on extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an official extension-- [Microsoft Teams Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.vss-services-teams).

With using this, you are able to see activity about your Azure DevOps or Team Foundation Server projects directly in your Microsoft Teams channel, for example:

- Work item updates
- Pull requests
- Code commits
- Builds
- Release deployments and approvals
- Work item updates
- Azure DevOps Kanban board

However, as the link declare clearly, it only work with Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2 and above.  It's not able to do this with TFS2015. You need to upgrade your TFS version. With higher version, you could also get more released new features in TFS.

[image]